# Selenium save website value in variable with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a script which clicks on buttons on my website to show specific values. I want to save these specific values in a python Variable. The problem is that those values only show up after i clicked some buttons, so i cant us beautifulsoup, because it would scan the website without my values, so i need to scan the values with selenium. Does somebody know how to do this? Im thankfully for any answer.

```
value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/span[1]"))).getAttribute("value") # get value
```

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. Are you wanting locators or ??? You haven't provided any of the relevant HTML so we can't write locators. You click the button then get the text/value from the element after the click. Update your question with the relevant HTML, properly formatted, and be clearer on what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the webdriver Selenium instance to get the page source (HTML). Like `driver.page_source`. You can assign it to a variable and parse it accordingly.

Reference: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html

Comment: Why would you want to parse the entirety of the page source to find some values that could be easily found on the page using locators when you're already using Selenium?

Comment: That would only work if the elements are deterministic in nature. Having the entire page source gives you more flexibility and power in customizing your logic. But of course, your point is correct if the question only needs one element (by xpath/id etc). The question mentioned BeautifulSoup so giving this may have been what the asker was looking for.

Comment: If the elements aren't "deterministic in nature", neither scenario is going to work. You can't parse the entire page source if you don't know what you are looking for. BUT... you don't have to write a parser if you use Selenium.